# How can I update the label value when the value changes?

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to update "Player's health." when "Player" attacks a target. Player's health is reduced based on the target's return damage.

My Game class (where the label is):

```
public partial class Game : Form
{
    public static Wizard wizard;
    public static Assasin assasin;

    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Battle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Battle battle = new Battle();
        battle.Show();
    }

    public void Game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameLabel.Text = HeroMaker.className;
        if (HeroMaker.wizardChoosen)
        {
            wizard = new Wizard(HeroMaker.className);
            HealthLabel.Text = wizard.Health.ToString();
            DamageLabel.Text = wizard.AttackDamage.ToString();
            HealthBar.Maximum = wizard.Health;
            HealthBar.Value = wizard.Health;
        }

    }
}
```

My Battle class (when attacking is happening) :

```
 public partial class Battle : Form
{
    Creature troll = CreaturesFactory.CreateCreature(CreatureType.Troll);
    public Battle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AttackTroll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Game.wizard.Health -= troll.ReturnDamage;
        //TODO: Update the "HealthLabel value."
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I attack the troll, Player's health is decreasing but its not updating on the label. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You'll have to write code that updates the label each time the players health changes. You could create a `HealthChanged` event in the `Wizard` class (or in whatever base class `Wizard` and `Assassin` have in common) and raise it in the `Health` propery setter, then register an event handler in the `Game` form code that updates the label.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the label:

```
private void AttackTroll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Game.wizard.Health -= troll.ReturnDamage;
    //TODO: Update the "HealthLabel value."
    HealthLabel.Text = wizard.Health.ToString();
    //any other things that need to be updated
}
```

You can also bind the label value like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147043/bind-a-label-to-a-variable).

Similarly, you can hook up an `event` such as `OnWizardHealthChange` that updates the label value whenever the HP changes. This way, you won't need to remember to add `HealthLabel.Text = wizard.Health.ToString();` everywhere the health changes. There's an example of this in the question that I linked.

EDIT:

You can try looking in the code-behind where the label is created to see its access modifier (is it `public`?)

Or, you can try this:

```
Label healthLabel = (Label)Application.OpenForms["FormName"].Controls.OfType<Label>().First(x=> x.Name == "LabelName");
```

Note that I haven't tested it but you should be able to at least get the label using this code and then update the value there. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566/best-way-to-access-a-control-on-another-form-in-windows-forms) is a good discussion on accessing controls (such as your label) in another form.

Comment: I don't have access to this label, since its in different form ? I am kinda new in forms.

Comment: @ДениславАнгелов can you add the code where you're creating the label?

Comment: I am just drag and dropping it at the form. Is that bad thing to do ?

Comment: @ДениславАнгелов Please see my edit for a few suggestions on accessing the label.