# Question on EventHandler from Josh Smith's MVVM sample application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling

The following code is from the MVVM sample by Josh Smith:

```
/// <summary>
/// Raised when this workspace should be removed from the UI.
/// </summary>
public event EventHandler RequestClose;

void OnRequestClose()
{
    //if (RequestClose != null)
    //        RequestClose(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    EventHandler handler = this.RequestClose;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
 }
```

The commented lines are my addition. My question is the commented lines would do the same thing as the uncommented lines right? So why create another EventHandler reference? Or am I missing something here? Thanks

Comment: To prevent problem with multiple threads trying to register or unregister the event

Comment: Can you please elaborate or provide a link for further reading? I don't see how creating another reference to the same object mitigates that problem.

Comment: How exactly does that help? Do you have any reference or something for that? I don't see anything that would help with multiple threads except a pretty minor delay caused by the assignment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672638/use-of-null-check-in-event-handler/672666#672666

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link Tanmoy, if you post an answer I can upvote it too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tanmoy is right. This is done to prevent possibility of RequestClose being changed (to null, for example) in other thread after your "if" but before your "RequestClose()".

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference - you are acting on the same event reference in both cases.  I prefer your commented code.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The RequestClose may be set to null or to another object, possibly by another thread since that is an instance variable. Assigning the value to a local variable means that you will always have a reference to the event and it can't be changed by other threads. Hope this helps.